# Kitematic + MariaDB + SequelPro

Tags: docker, containers, sequelpro

I'm recently using `Kitematic (Docker)`, Struggling between `Vagrant` and `Docker`.

Working with Docker and Kitematic is smooth, I can create, initiate a `DB` via `Console`.

But If I want to manipulate the db via sequel pro, or just import from local, I can't.

The issue is:

Trying to access via Sequel Pro ,I get the error `IP is un-accessible`

In other case I can `rsync` a backup file , using `mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < filename.sql` and voilà .

But either, I can't `rsyc` in the MariaDb Container .

Having access with sequel pro would be the must practical way.

Can anybody show me the correct path or guide on how to make docker `mariadb` container available via `sequel pro`.